# Describing mixins in a declaration file

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Assume an existing Javascript framework for which you want to create typings. The Javascript code uses Node.js modules, prototypical inheritance and mixins:

```
// File: src/lib/a.js

function A() {
  this.isA = true;
  this.type = 'a';
}

module.exports = A;

// File: src/lib/b.js

var A = require('./a');
var plugin = require('./plugin');

function B() {
  A.call(this);
  this.isB = true;
  this.type = 'b';
  plugin(this);
}

B.prototype = object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

module.exports = B;

// File: src/lib/plugin.js

function plugin(obj) {
  obj.doSomethingFancy = function() {
    // ...
  }
}

module.exports = plugin;
```

How would you describe `B` in a declaration file so that it conveys that some members are created by/through its constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need this distinction? Your constructors always create those members, so if you have an object of type `B` - you can be sure those properties will be there.

If you want to signal, that a member might not exist - suffix it's name with `?` like I did for `doSomethinFancy` in the example bellow.

```
class A {
    public isA: boolean;
    public type: string;

    constructor() {
        this.isA = true;
        this.type = 'a';
    }
}

function plugin(obj: any): any {
    obj.doSomethingFancy = function() {
        // ...
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public isB: boolean;

    // same could be used for optional function arguments
    public doSomethingFancy?: () => {};

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.isB = true;
        this.type = 'b';
        plugin(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is about ambient declarations, not the implementation. Also, for the sake of argument, assume that a child class might decide not to call its parent constructor.

Comment: @ciss I'm not aware of a way to convey the fact members are created by constructor. If you want to convey the possibility of a member being undefined - suffix it with `?`, like `isA?`. Speaking of derived type not calling base type constructor, this is likely to result in TS error, but if this is just a library definition - you can tell your compiler to ignore errors in external libraries.